# stdbool.h and float.h libraries are not linking to my program

Tags: c, eclipse

My Computer Science teacher gave me a template for an assignment on manipulating arrays. This includes the `<stdbool.h>` and `<float.h>` libraries. Both of these seem to not be linking. When using the  library I always have to link it by right clicking on the file in the file explorer of eclipse then going to properties> C/C++ Build> Settings> Libraries> and then clicking "add..." and typing "m". All of my type "bool" and symbols "true" and "false" form the `<stdbool.h>` library cannot be resolved and my symbol "FLT_EPSILON" which is a constant defined in the `<float.h>` library cannot be resolved. I don't know how to link these libraries or fix this. thank you

EDIT:

I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
/* function sqrt() is defined in <math.h> */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <float.h>
```

at the top of my program

Comment: Have you `#include`'d the files?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your Library Path properly configured in Eclipse? It sound like it is not looking in the correct directory, which is why you always need to set it again

Comment: These files are not libraries, you don't need to add them to your linker's input file list - you just need to `#include` them in your source file, as @Inspired noted.

Comment: yes I did have the #include <library name> in my file I just forgot to state that.

Comment: @engineer Failure to resolve can be related to the toolchain you are using (which you didn't specify). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: it does appear to be working now for some reason tho

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the source file in which you want to use the bool type and FLT_EPSILON constant add these lines:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <float.h>
```

and you should be ok. This works for my using **Eclipse Kepler SR1**, no need to add any external libraries.

Edit: These includes can fail to resolve if the compiler used with the selected toolchain doesn't support them. For instance they can't be resolved when using MS VC++ as current toolchain (presumably because that compiler isn't C99 compliant). If you are using MS VC++ try switching toolchain to MinGW GCC for instance.